# Android - GCM push notifications not appearing in notifications list

Tags: java, android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on my first Android app to use the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) service for push notifications.  I've got to the point where I can successfully send a message from my server application, and log the content of the message in the onMessage event within my GCMIntentService class on the client app.  However I don't see any visual indication on the device that a message was received.  I was expecting the message to appear in the pull-down notifications list on the phone, as it does on the iPhone.  Does this have to be coded manually?  Also is there a common method for displaying the message regardless of which activity is currently active, and if the app is idle in the background?  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will generate a notification in the android system bar at the top of the screen. This code will create a new intent that will direct the user to a "Home.class" after clicking on the notification in the top bar. If you would like it to do something specific based on the current activity you could send broadcast requests from the GCMIntentService to your other activities.

```
Intent notificationIntent=new Intent(context, Home.class);
generateNotification(context, message, notificationIntent);

private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, Intent notificationIntent) {
    int icon = R.drawable.icon;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Note that this example uses resources in R.drawable and R.String that will need to be present to work but it should give you the idea. See this for more information about status notifications http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/index.html and this about broadcast recievers. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Hi, i have used this plugin https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova and followed all instructions. however, i can only get messages when within app, but cant get the app to display notifications in androids notification area. please advise. I use this plugin cause i use phonegap @Zachary Moshansky

Comment: I'm sorry but I have never used Phonegap and am unable to comment on how to make notifications work with it

Comment: @ZacharyMoshansky. I am trying to develop an app which needs push notification service..I am receiving notifications, can able to see them if they are clicked. The issue comes if I test the app on Google Nexus having (Android 4.4 KitKat)...it also receives notification but clicking on them does not open the desired Activity. Does it have anything to do with Intent flags?

Comment: Never mind I just tried to debug the app in the same phone got a Permission Denial: starting Intent exception and resolved it....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GcmListenerService you can use this code, add to your onMessageReceived the sendNotification()

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        sendNotification(message);
}

private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOURCLASS.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_park_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Ppillo Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```